# Windows 10 wants to repair "drive errors" on my dual-boot setup

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

Unfortunately, I don't know how to get any additional data on what it wants to repair, but I'm afraid of just letting it do what it thinks is right in case it destroys my Ubuntu setup.

I have a Samsung Series 9 laptop which originally came with Windows 8. I upgraded to Win 8.1, then added Ubuntu 12.04 and finally upgraded Windows to Win 10, so that might explain the number of partitions.

My partitions in GParted:
[image: My partitions in GParted]

I'll appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Is Windows telling you what partition it wants to repair?  Normally, it can't even read EXT4 (at least in versions I know).

Comment: I can't say for sure but looking at this it seems that your partition 4 has issues .. seeing that it is 62 or so GB and NTFS I would assume that it is your Windows partition. So your Windows partition has errors on it and that is most likely what Windows is trying to fix. Windows can't read ext4 or linux-swap file systems and shouldn't touch them at all. I would say that you should be pretty safe to allow Windows to repair the issues with its partition .. unless it screws up the partition table somehow .. you should be fine.

Comment: If you don't know what's broken, then how are you planning to repair it? Get into Windows, use the Command Prompt and type: chkdsk , then add the results to your question. Maybe take a look here: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/fix-hard-drives-chkdsk-windows-10/ . Most probably Win has some problem with sda5 , the ntfs partition. I have a backup partition just like that, and Win seems bothered every time a write files from Ubuntu into that partition.

Comment: no partitions 5 and 6 are recovery images from the factory to restore the laptop back to the way it was when first purchased. Those partitions also are not in the mix of Windows 10 wanting to do a repair. Those only come into play if in Windows 10 he chose the recovery option of using an image to restore the system... chkdsk is probably what is trying to fix errors and what prompted this question in the first place

Comment: Your msftres, sda3 must be unformatted, so gparted normally shows an error, but it is correct. Your sda4 is you main Windows install and you probably left Windows fast startup or always on hibernation on. Linux will not mount the hibernated NTFS partition. So from Linux we cannot tell what issue Windows is having.

Comment: That partition table is a mess.

Comment: @AndroidDev Not very helpful, but nevertheless true. Do you have any suggestions besides getting rid of all the recoveries? I saw the unallocated partition, but don't know how to make that reuseable again since it's "stuck", I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So running `chkdsk /f` and rebooting twice fixed my sda4 Windows partition, I guess I just was paranoid since the Windows message said it wants to repair "a drive".

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer with the check-mark on the left to close the question. Thank you :)

Comment: @MadMike Wish that I could.. 23 hours remaining :P

Comment: @Vipr do it now!